# Ich hatte ihn erst gestern nicht gekannt-meaning of "erst"

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence taken from a book:

> Ich hatte ihn erst gestern nicht gekannt.

Pursuant to Dict.cc, the most likely translation of "erst" in the context given would be "not until". But doesn't this essentially create a double negation since "nicht" is already present here?

Comment: Which book? What is the context? Without clarification, all answers will be guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence sounds not really wrong, but strange and un-idiomatic to me, I would never write or say it that way.

"Not until" can not be a translation of "erst". What they probably mean is that "erst gestern nicht" can be translated as "not until yesterday".

> I had not known him until yesterday.

Which isn't entirely correct because it implies that I got to know him already yesterday. The German sentence doesn't say that, it just says that as late as yesterday I didn't know him.

More literally (and equally strange-sounding):

> Yesterday I still had not known him.

I would say

> Ich hatte ihn noch gestern nicht gekannt.

Answer (score 1):

"erst gestern" can have two meanings: 1. "as late as yesterday" (background assumption: it should have been earlier than yesterday) 2. "just yesterday, therefore, quite recently".

Maybe your example was intended to be "Ich hatte ihn erst gestern nicht erkannt"? (just guessing) Then the second meaning would probably be relevant. You would say that if you often fail to recognise people, and not recognising that person yesterday is a very recent example of this (underlining your present condition).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is indeed a bit strange, and I would need more context, but it can be meant as:

> It was just yesterday that I didn't know him.

No double negation.

Comment: That's clearly a better translation than my literal one. but it's Plusquamperfekt in German for some undisclosed reason, so "... that I hadn't known him".